# grep: option requires an argument -- 'm'

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

I'm trying to grep a file in order to find a line containing this text: "-m".

I've created this file to test this issue:

```bsh
echo "min-value: 2" >> test.txt
echo "original-matrix: 10" > test.txt
echo "total-points: 55" >> test.txt
```

When I run this command I get that error:

```bsh
filizaum@asus-pc ~ $ echo test.html | grep "-m"
grep: option requires an argument -- 'm'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

How can i grep with that string?

Comment: use `grep -e '-m'` or `grep -- '-m'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` thinks, that `-m` is an *option*, the quotes don't matter, they are interpreted by `bash`, not by `grep`.

> -m NUM, --max-count=NUM

You should use `--` to tell `grep` that no argument follows:

```
grep -- "-m"
```

See here: [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)